# Grunt build no min but concat all js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, gruntjs

I'm using yeoman and backbone. My app works without any error before I run grunt build.

But as soon I did a grunt build and run the app from the dist then some page can't load as there're some error. It's hard to debug while the file is already minified.

I wonder if there's a way still concat all the files into the main js but not minified?

Here's the gruntfile. It's from the yeoman generator but I added field lines from other internet example so it works with require js.

Anyone know how I can only concat but no min? Thanks.

module.exports = function (grunt) {

```
// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-requirejs');

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths
var config = {
    app: '.',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({
    requirejs: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                baseUrl : '<%= config.app %>/scripts/',
                name : 'main',
                mainConfigFile : '<%= config.app %>/scripts/main.js',
                out : '.tmp/concat/scripts/main.js'
            //include: ['../bower_components/requirejs/require.js']
            }
        }
    },

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['bowerInstall']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            open: true,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                open: false,
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    bowerInstall: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
            exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js']
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
        },
        html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
        'assets/**/*',
                    'bower_components/**/*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer'
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
'requirejs:dist',
    //'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Add `optimize: 'none'` to your requirejs config:

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl : '<%= config.app %>/scripts/',
            name : 'main',
            optimize: 'none', // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            mainConfigFile : '<%= config.app %>/scripts/main.js',
            out : '.tmp/concat/scripts/main.js'
        //include: ['../bower_components/requirejs/require.js']
        }
    }
}
```

The [example `r.js`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L98) configuration states the following:

```
//How to optimize all the JS files in the build output directory.
//Right now only the following values
//are supported:
//- "uglify": (default) uses UglifyJS to minify the code.
//- "uglify2": in version 2.1.2+. Uses UglifyJS2.
//- "closure": uses Google's Closure Compiler in simple optimization
//mode to minify the code. Only available if running the optimizer using
//Java.
//- "closure.keepLines": Same as closure option, but keeps line returns
//in the minified files.
//- "none": no minification will be done.
optimize: "uglify",
```